# Google books preview not available

Tags: google-books

**Edit:** problem solved by @Sathya in comments. It suffices to replace all instances of 358 by 97 in the wrong link that was given to me. I am still curious why such a link makes the page available, while it is not (for me) if I simply go to the preview directly, or if I scroll to page 97 after I have followed the wrong 358 link.

Recently, I followed a link to a Google Books preview where the page was not available in my case, while it was for the person who had shared the link.

I was advised to refresh my browser, clear the cookies, try another browser. I did all that and tried with Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. No success.

Then I was advised to use stealthy extension, in case it was a location problem, as I am in Canada. It did not work either.

[Here is the link](http://books.google.rs/books?id=hIEnzrOBbW0C&pg=PA358&lpg=PA358&dq=every%20compact%20space%20is%20a%20continuous%20image%20of%20a%20moscow%20space&source=bl&ots=fVNdS65_ud&sig=Fm0RqNKUht0Eh_vGx58MzVLtgz4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=75JJUcerKuiU0QXw1YDoDg&sqi=2&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Theprem%2022.1&f=false) I was provided. Note that the page I was supposed to reach was page 97. And not the page 358, which I can see. So I scrolled up to page 97, and it was not visible for me, while the link provider claims page 97 was visible for him.

Could you tell me what the possible reason is?

Comment: Could you post the link?

Comment: @Sathya Good idea, thanks. Edited.

Comment: Looking at the link, `http://books.google.rs/books?id=hIEnzrOBbW0C&pg=PA358&lpg=PA358` it's supposed to take you to Page 358. Change it to 97 & it takes you there

Comment: @Sathya Yes, that was a mistake of the link provider. But of course, I scrolled up to page 97 which I can't see. While this person claims he could see it.

Comment: @Sathya You're right! It was not about scrolling up, but replacing 358 in the link by 97. How strange. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the link, `http://books.google.rs/books?id=hIEnzrOBbW0C&pg=PA358&lpg=PA358` it's supposed to take you to Page 358. Change it to 97 & it takes you there.

I also tried scrolling from page 358 to 97, that worked for me as well. Google Books Preview doesn't show all the pages, but in this case page 97 was available  so scrolling should take you there.

Comment: No, scrolling does not work for me after the 358 link. Strange...

Answer (score 0):

To see a wider range of pages in googlebooks one can try these options:

1. remove googlebooks cookies in your browser and browse again.
2. try another broswer. for example try Opera, Konqueror, etc
3. use an ip-changer extension/widget or a VPN.
4. try another computer or a virtual machine.
5. try books.google.com/books.google.com.uk/books.google.sr/etc
6. use UA proofer extension for Chrome.
7. wait one or two weeks and then try again.

And finally

8.. buy the book from amazon.com.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not answer my question. The question is: why does the initial link not work for me? A partial and satisfactory answer is given by Sathya: replace both instances of 358 by 97 in the address. Now it works, without any of your suggestions above. It still remains unclear why scrolling works for Sathya, and not for me.